# Update não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, crud

No meu sistema tem uma página de cadastro e uma página com uma tabela com as informações dos cadastrados. Nessa tabela tem um botão de edição que linka com um formulário igual da página de cadastro.

**O que deveria acontecer:**

Ao clicar no botão salvar, os campos modificados deveriam ser alterados no registro.

**O que está acontecendo:**

Quando tento alterar o registro aparece o `alert` de "salvo com sucesso" e volta pra página anterior, como deveria acontecer. Mas olhando pelo phpMyAdmin, o registro continua inalterado

**A conexão:**

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacao");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

**Formulário de edição:**

```
<?php
    require 'conn.php';
    $queryColaboradores = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT FORMACAO FROM participantes");
    $turma = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TURMA');
    $formacao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FORMACAO');
    $colaborador = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'COLABORADOR');
    $Realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
    var_dump($queryColaboradores);
?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
                <p> </p>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateEdicao.php" style="
                        text-align: left;
                        margin-top:50px;">
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?php echo $formacao; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA" value="<?php echo $turma; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">Colaborador: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR" value="<?php echo $colaborador; ?>">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                                text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="TURMA">ID participante: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PARTICIPANTE" name="PARTICIPANTE" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <fieldset disabled>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="previsto">Status</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" class="form-control" value="Previsto">
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" style="
                                text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="REALIZADO">Realizado: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="REALIZADO" name="REALIZADO" value="Realizado">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**O update:**

```
<?php

$previsto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PREVISTO');
$realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');

$strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$sql = " UPDATE participantes SET REALIZADO = '$realizado' WHERE ID = '$id' ";
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro. " . mysqli_error($strcon));
mysqli_close($strcon);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

var_dump($id)
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa coluna do banco REALIZADO e esse id são que tipo de campo? Varchar? Se sim falta uma aspas simples

Comment: O ID é um int auto_increment, já o REALIZADO é um varchar

Comment: Agora aparece que o alert com o aviso "salvo com sucesso" e redireciona para a página anterior, como deveria acontecer, mas quando abro o phpmyadmin o registro não foi alterado.

Comment: Ja tentou dar um echo no $sql gerado para ver se esta certinho e até mesmo executa-lo na mao para ter certeza

Comment: Eu cheguei a dar um var_dump($previsto, $realizado, $id) deu NULL NULL NULL. Dei um no sql também e deu a linha de código que o sql recebe mas sem o ID

Comment: Então é por isso. Sua clausula where está vindo com o valor vazio. Voce está dizendo pra seu mysql: "Atualize a coluna REALIZADO onde o id for igual a nada". Como você não tem nenhum registro onde o id é igual a nada ele não alterada nada.

Comment: Sim, mas agora eu já apresentei o ID, mas ainda assim não está atualizando. Dei outro var_dump($id) e a resposta ainda é NULL.

Comment: Mas se você trocou na $sql por $ID, terá que trocar em todos os lugares também, tudo que for $id você tem que trocar pra $ID

Comment: Não o $id mas o ID.    'ID'=$id

Answer (score 2):

Veja se com esse update funciona! Se você olhar bem, tem alguns conflitos com aspas duplas e simples, e também erros com ponto e virgula.

Para editar somente a coluna com o id que você precisa, o $id você também vai ter que pegar como POST:

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';
$queryColaboradores = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT FORMACAO FROM participantes");
$turma = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TURMA');
$formacao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'FORMACAO');
$colaborador = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'COLABORADOR');
$Realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');
var_dump($queryColaboradores);
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1 style="
                margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
            <p> </p>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateEdicao.php" style="
                      text-align: left;
                      margin-top:50px;">
                    <fieldset disabled>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" style="
                                 text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?php echo $formacao; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset disabled>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                                 text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA" value="<?php echo $turma; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset disabled>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                                 text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="TURMA">Colaborador: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR" value="<?php echo $colaborador; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset disabled>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                                 text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="TURMA">Id: </label>
                                <input  type="number" required class="form-control" id="ID" name="ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <fieldset disabled>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="previsto">Status</label>
                                <input type="text" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" class="form-control" value="Previsto">
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="REALIZADO" id="REALIZADO" value="REALIZADO" aria-label="...">REALIZADO
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
    $previsto = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'PREVISTO');
    $realizado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'REALIZADO');
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID');

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = " UPDATE participantes SET REALIZADO = '$realizado' WHERE id = '$id' ";
    mysqli_query($strcon, $sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
                window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Ah, bem mais limpinho e organizado! Então, copiei seu código mas ainda não atualiza a coluna REALIZADO que é a que deveria atualizar.

Comment: De onde vem aquela variável $id?

Comment: Remova depois o WHERE id = '$id' e me diga se funciona. pôs essa variável $id pelo meu ver, não está sendo informada em lugar nenhum.

Comment: Removi e a coluna Realizado FINALMENTE foi alterada, mas o problema é que foi alterada de todos os registros, e eu queria alterar só no registro que está sendo editado.

Comment: Vai ter que pegar esse $id por POST também, igual faz com o PREVISTO e o REALIZADO, algo do tipo: $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ID'); Ai no caso, vai enviar junto com o PREVISTO e o REALIZADO. Eu editei pra você entender melhor.

Comment: Então, eu acabei de fazer isso, mas voltou a não alterar.

Comment: Sim, pôs você não está enviando o id por POST, terá que enviar no formulário de edição. Igual você faz com o PREVISTO e o REALIZADO. Terá também que enviar um ID, editei mais uma vez, veja se você consegue entender.

Comment: Eu fiz as alterações recomendadas, só mudei o 'id' para 'ID' mas ainda não está alterando. Acha que seria melhor eu fazer um campo no formulário pra armazenar esse ID?

Comment: Mudou de id pra ID onde?

Comment: Na variável $sql

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65135/discussion-between-mariana-ferreira-and-lucas-carvalho).

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou dar um `var_dump` na *Query* que está rodando e rodar ela diretamente no *PhpMyAdmin*? Geralmente o *MySql* dá uma informação mais relevante sobre o **ERRO** da *Query*...

Uma outra dica é tentar criar a *Query* diretamente no *MySql*, (no seu caso, na interface do *PhpMyAdmin*), com dados estáticos, e uma vez que funcionar, migrá-la para o *PHP*.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua query, `UPDATE participantes SET REALIZADO='$realizado' WHERE id='$id'`, a cláusula WHERE tenta usar a variável $id, que não estava declarada antes, e também não está sendo passada pelo formulário. Você precisa criar o campo ID no formulário HTML e passar ele.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
```

Outros pontos para observar:

### Mensagem de erro

Essa mensagem não ajuda muito, seria interessante também logar o erro, ou escrever mesmo o erro direto na mensagem, porém este último caso pode não ser interessante por mostrar o problema ao usuário final.

Se não tiver problema mostrar, pode trocar no código para:

```
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar atualizar registro. " . mysqli_error($strcon));
```

### Usar "prepared statement"

Do jeito que está, sua query não é segura, da uma olhada nesse assunto. Saiba mais aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

### Escrevendo em atributos

No código atual, se por acaso o nome do colaborador for escrito como *João "Mito" da Silva*, vai quebrar seus atributos. Utiliza onde escreve os atributos o seguinte:

```
<label  for="COLABORADOR">Colaborador: </label>
<input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR" value="<?php echo htmlentities($colaborador, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

Note também que troquei o atributo `for` do `label`, pois ele é o label desse input.

Comment: Hey, obrigada pela resposta! Fiz o campo hyden e ele ta puxando o ID do cadastro, mas ainda não tá sendo alterado o registro. Vou editar minha pergunta.

Comment: Deixa eu fazer uma pergunta meio extra. Eu incluí o hidden no campo ID e o value do meu campo ID recebeu o ID. Então, se eu incluir o hidden nos meus outros campos, o value dos meus outros campos também vão receber as informações deles armazenadas no banco de dados?